# Search with 2 letters at same time

Tags: android, textview, autocompletetextview, android-search

I have AutoCompleteTextview in my Activity.And when I type text from keyboard it searches on that first letter from my database. Everything works fine but now I want to improve my app.I want to make my textview work like this: When users selects for example character "a", it will show me words which starts with "a" also with "ä". And also for the characters such as: n-ň,  o-ö, s-ş, u-ü.
I have tried to do smth like this:

```
textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    if(s.length() != 0 && !textView.isPerformingCompletion()){
//                      Log.i("HOLA", "textwatcher is here");
                        ArrayAdapter<String>  adapter;
                        String word = s.toString();
                        switch (word){

                            case "a":

                                word = "ä";

                                wl = db.getWordList(word);
                                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, wl.getWordList());
                                textView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            default:
                                wl = db.getWordList(word);
                                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, wl.getWordList());
                                textView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should use switch(word.charAt(0)) instead of switch(word) and add a case for 'ä' and others too.

Comment: @twenk11k I'll try